# arraylist display in rows and columns dynamically

Tags: jsp, dynamic, arraylist, rows

I have an arraylist.Want to display the values in rows and columns dynamically.eg
if the size of arrylist is 59 i would keep the column configurable like 20 or 15 and divide the size by columns and get the no. of rows to display the data in array list.I am not able to figure out the looping. This is to be done in jsp with  and 
Say i have kept columns as 15 . 59/15 =3 , so the no of rows = 3+1=4, 45 values in 3 rows and 14 in the 4th row. Depending the column configured it should be displayed in the next row.

eg:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31....(for no of columns =15).

but if configure noofcolumns=10
then it should display values in 10 columns and 6 rows(10 in each row and 9 in the 6th row).I am trying to diaply in  in jsp .

thanks

Update:

This is my code but it prints the value in one one column..vertically inside the div..would like it to display in 15 columns and 4 rows in the

```
ArrayList<String> list= someList.get(1);     
for(int j= 1;j< list.size();j++) { 
String value = list.get(j); 
    { 
    %> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxid" value="<%=value%>" /><%=value %><br /> </td> <%
    }
} 
%>
```

Comment: You should post your code so we can guide you through a solution.

Comment: ArrayList<String> list=  someList.get(1);   
    
   for(int j= 1;j< list.size();j++)
   {
    String value = list.get(j);
    
    { %>
    <td>             
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxid" value="<%=value%>" /><%=value %><br />
     </td>
    
    
    <%}} %>    This is my code but it prints the value in one one column..vertically inside the div..would like it to display in 15 columns and 4 rows in the <div>

Answer (score 0):

You should try to have 2 loops. iterate rows with column. Make sure u have a correct object structure for the data dispaly and iterattion.

Think more about framing to correct  object structure